# Constant terms in variational inference and lower bounds

Tags: autoencoders, variational-bayes, variational-inference

I have a model for which the lower bound takes the following form

$
\log p(x) \geq \mathbb{E}_{recog}[\log \frac{gen}{recog}]  + \mathcal{c}
$

where *recog* and *gen* denote the factorization in the recognition and generative models, respectively, and *c* is

$
\mathcal{c} \propto \log(2),
$

i.e., a constant term. Given that the optimization is over the family of variational densities, (I guess that) the constant term can be dropped. However, I cannot find any previous paper, or any other reference, where the lower bound has a constant term. At least not in the field of variational autoencoders.

Does anyone know if it is usual to remove constant terms in the lower bound? ideally with a reference.